# Negative impact of setting Apache's LimitRequestFieldSize very high?

Tags: http-headers

On apache httpd 2.2, I would like to increase the value of `LimitRequestFieldSize` to 48k or maybe even 65k.

Has anyone experience with setting the value of `LimitRequestFieldSize` to such high values? Any negative impact, besides the increased attack surface?